# I'm accidentally added a physical volume without filesystem to a volume group and one of logical volumes, how can I make a filesystem for it online?

Tags: lvm

Because the logical volume is mounted as my root partition, and I don't want to fix this with some LiveCD (it's very troublesome).

By the `lvs` command the logical volume has already the new (larger) size, but by the `df` command it still has the old (smaller) size.

Comment: I can't parse "I'm accidentally added a physical volume without filesystem to a volume group and one of logical volumes". What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use resize2fs to extend the filesystem to the size of logical volume. You can do this on the fly (w/o need to unmount the filesystem)

```
resize2fs /path/to/logical_volume_device
```

Comment: Yes I've found that answer somewhere else 2 seconds after I posted this question. But still thank you!

Comment: Unmounting is generally a good idea, I think.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, yes, it is good idea. But on 24/7 systems you just can't do it. Or for / (root) fs you should use some livecd. I personally use it w/o unmount for years and to the moment i do not saw any problem